# How to Customize just the property pane without building webpart

Tags: properties, sharepoint-online, spfx, pane, spfx-extension

Does anyone know how can I show the property pane without creating webpart?

I want to show the property pane after clicking the User Management icon, which is created with extension

[image]

Comment: Hello, i believe that you are looking at the problem through a wrong perspective. You should be trying to implement a solution that resembles the property pane instead of calling the property pane controls. The property pane is a really specific plane of configuration of the web part and should not be accessible to all users.
you could try incorporation the below package into an spfx web part : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sliding-pane/v/6.0.0

if i have sometime i'll try making it as a poc, although i am not sure if such library would be able to perform under all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [repo](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-aadtokenprovider-bot) which has some of the official samples from the SPFx extensions model and depicts a pretty close use-case to the one that you are searching, there is an element in [Fluent UI called Panel](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/panel).

As it is written in the documentation:

> Panels are overlays that contain supplementary content and are used for complex creation, edit, or management experiences.  For example, viewing details about an item in a list or editing settings.

Furthermore, scouring the repo we can see that the panel is triggered:

```
...
import { Panel, PanelType } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Panel";
...
class GraphBot extends React.Component<IGraphBotProps, IGraphBotState> {

....
    public render() {
    // Be careful, the user Id is mandatory to be able to use the bot state service (i.e privateConversationData)
    return (
        <div className={ styles.banner }>
            <ActionButton onClick= { this._login } checked={ true } iconProps={ { iconName: "Robot", className: styles.banner__chatButtonIcon } } className={ styles.banner__chatButton}>     
                { strings.GraphBotButtonLabel }              
            </ActionButton>
            <Panel
                isOpen={ this.state.showPanel }
                type={ PanelType.medium}
                isLightDismiss={ true }
                onDismiss={ () => this.setState({ showPanel: false }) }
            >
                { this.state.isBotInitializing ? 
                ....                    
                }                    
            </Panel>
        </div>
    );
}
```

There is an `<ActionButton>` with an OnClick Eventhandler to execute the below function :

```
private async _login()  {

    this.setState({
        isBotInitializing :true,
        showPanel: true,
    });
....
```

The above function sets the `showPanel` prop to `true` and this prop is used in the Panel Component, where it checks when set to true to open the Panel and move on with the Business Logic of the application extension.

The same can be seen in the Fluent UI Documentation [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/panel#usage), in the basic example.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { Panel } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Panel';
import { useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';

export const PanelBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, { setTrue: openPanel, setFalse: dismissPanel }] = useBoolean(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <DefaultButton text="Open panel" onClick={openPanel} />
      <Panel
        headerText="Sample panel"
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onDismiss={dismissPanel}
        // You MUST provide this prop! Otherwise screen readers will just say "button" with no label.
        closeButtonAriaLabel="Close"
      >
        <p>Content goes here.</p>
      </Panel>
    </div>
  );
};
```